# How to get attributes from parent?

Tags: python

Let's say we have these classes:

```
class Foo(object):
    _bar = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "hello"

    def getBar(self):
        return self._bar

    def setBar(self, bar):
        self._bar = bar

    def getAttributes(self):
        for attr in self.__dict__:
            print attr

    bar = property(getBar, setBar)

class Child(Foo):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.a = ""
        self.b = ""
```

if I do something like:

```
child = Child()
child.getAttributes()
```

I get all the attributes from parent and child. How could I get the attributes only from the parent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to call getAttributes of the Foo class via child ??

Comment: Why not just call `Foo.getAttributes()`?

Comment: This a example. In my real program, a lot of classes extend from the main one. I have a list with variables from those classes, but I just wanna access the attributes from the parent. So for example, I call getAttributes I don't know which class is

Comment: Sounds like your design is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick example (which may, or not be what you want):

```
child.__class__.__bases__[0]().getAttributes()
```

*Edit*: to clarify things a bit: `__base__` is a class attribute containing tuple of base classes for this class. Since your *Child* class has only one base class *Foo*, i'm just selecting first element of this tuple. Using your data as an input, it will produce:

```
>>> child.getAttributes()
a
_bar
b

>>> child.__class__.__bases__[0]().getAttributes()
_bar
```

Comment: It doesn't work out. I did dir(child.__class__) and don't see that built in function

Comment: @bribon: *__bases__* attribute is not reported by *dir()* AFAIK

Comment: — Maybe I misunderstood the question. Do you realize that your second construction, which uses `__bases__` to find the name `_bar`, is listing the *class attributes only* of the superclass, and that any instance attributes set in the superclass's `__init__` will not appear in the list? For example: you are *not* printing `bar`, which I had thought would be a requirement since that is an attribute of instances of the parent class.

Comment: @Brandon Craig Rhodes: yes, i do; the main idea was to give a hint about *__bases__* attribute, which may or may not fit the needs in practical context. Also, from what i can see in given example, this is in sync with *child.getAttributes()*, which won't return superclass instance attributes either. By the way, *child.__class__.__bases__[0].__dict__*- will.

Comment: @Brandon Craig Rhodes: And yes, this is rather potentially *possible* way than *optimal* one and i'm glad you've commented.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Python stores all object attributes in the same place "on the object"; it does not break them out into separate storage areas, one per class in the inheritance hierarchy. The best you could do would be to keep a list of attributes that belonged to each level, maybe by having a `__slots__ = []` declaration in every class or maybe by keeping a less formal list of attribute names, and then doing a loop with `getattr()` inside (or a loop that looks directly in the object's `__dict__`?) to get that specific set of attributes.

What are you trying to do with this list of attributes? What do you want to accomplish with them? Maybe there is a better way to tackle your larger issue.

Comment: I use to __dict__ to render all the attributes from my classes and this way I can create a XML or JSON with the content of every object without calling by one by one each attribute. I got different approach, but your help is very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"How could I get the attributes only from the parent?"

There is no "parent", really. Child(Foo) is a class, so Foo is the "parent" here (although you usually call it "superclass"), but that relationship doesn't carry over to the instances.

When you instantiate the class by `child = Child()`, `child` has no parent. All it's attributes sit directly on the instance, so there is no parent, really. And that's why it becomes problematic. But as Brandon suggests, by using slots, or otherwise defining up which properties belong to which superclass, you can return only those defined in a particular class.

Why on earth you would want this is beyond me, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `getAttributes()` method in `class Foo` to:

```
def getAttributes(self):
    for attr in self.__class__.__bases__[0].__dict__:
        print attr
```

You'll then get the following results from calling it on a `Child` instance:

```
child = Child()
child.getAttributes()
# setBar
# __module__
# bar
# getAttributes
# __dict__
# __doc__
# __weakref__
# _bar
# __init__
# getBar
```