# Determine super class attributes from child class attributes in python

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b1='b1val'

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        # get base class attrs only (works)
        # EDIT: THIS DOES NOT WORK WHEN Child.data2 is called!
        self._base_attrs = self.__dict__
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        # internal attrs
        self._c2='c2val'
        # include only these in data 
        self.c1='c1val'


    def data1(self):
        # get base class attrs only (deos not work)
        super_attrs = super(Child, self).__dict__
        # return public attributes with values from child class only
        data = {k: v for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if v and k[0] != '_'
            and k not in super_attrs}
        return data

    def data2(self):
        # return public attributes with values from child class only
        data = {k: v for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if v and k[0] != '_'
            and k not in self._base_attrs}
        return data
```

Looking at `Child.data1`, `super_attrs` contains all attributes from `Base` & `Child`.  I thought this is strange...  `self._base_attrs` returns the following when `Child.data2` is called:

```
{'_base_attrs': {...}, '_c2': 'c2val', 'c1': 'c1val', 'b1': 'b1val'}
```

Is there any way to differentiate between Base attributes and Child attributes from a Child method?
I need to return a dictionary of only Child attributes...

Comment: Your code shows you getting the super from a different class (Item).

Comment: Not sure why you want to do this instead of normal inheritance. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `if Child._base_attrs == Child.base_attrs: edit()`

Comment: Item was a leftover from my source code, Should have been Child. Corrected

Comment: I'm not sure what typo you're referring to, but I'm talking about `_base_attrs` vs `base_attrs`.

Comment: got that one taken care of too! thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @keith This is normal inheritance.  I just need each child class to be able to return a dictionary of it's own attributes, unencumbered by it's base class attributes or private attributes.

Comment: How is `_c2` returned by `data2` if `k[0] != '_'`?

Comment: my bad again, that output was from _base_attrs when data2 is called. `{}` is output from data2

Comment: Well I have to wonder why you are needing this. A subclass should be a specialization of the superclass. I don't see a need for this that couldn't be done another way, such as composition.

Comment: @keith the need is: The base class contains a bunch of methods for performing calculations which all child classes will need.  The child classes each have their own set of public attributes.  Those public attributes will need to be converted to a dictionary serialized as json. The json output will then be sent to an external api.  If the external api gets any values it does not expect and error will be thrown.  Hence data must only return the public values contained in each child class. EX: Item(Base) will have different fields then Comment(base) but they both use Base methods and attrs.

Comment: But is the subclass a specialization of the superclass, or a container? In other words, can you say the subclass "is-a" type of superclass? If not, then you should use another design. You could also define a serialize method that explicitly lists the attributes you need to serialize. "Explicit is better than implicit". These kind of `__dict__` hacks can be fragile, and hard to maintain.

Comment: Here is why i went with inheritance. The base is PostableObject, the Item(PostableObject) is a PostableObject and so is Comment(PostableObject) and so is LocationItem(Item).  They all have local Model instances and must be converted to PostableItems expected by social providers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get attributes from parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502141/how-to-get-attributes-from-parent)

Comment: See Brandon Rhode's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4502323/1938621.

Comment: @RyneEverett Brandon Rhodes has answered the question.. You Cant. Not sure how i failed to find that answer on SA.  Thanks.

Comment: @Keith I see your point.  I have been playing with the design structure of this for a while and the line is very gray.. In light of Keiths's pointer to BrandonRhode's answer.  It would appear i made the wrong choice.  Thanks for your time, it was helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but relies on calling the parent constructor immediately:

```py
class Child(Parent):
   def __init__(self, ...):
       super().__init__(...)
       self._parent_attrib_names = list(self.__dict__.keys())
       self.child_only_attrib = True
   def get_child_attribs(self):
       return {attr: val for attr, val in self.__dict__.items()
               if attr not in self._parent_attrib_names}
```